# Integral polynomials dividing N!

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider a polynomial $P(X)\in\mathbb Z[X]$. Is it true that $P(N)$ divides $N!$ for infinitely many integer $N$?

This question is motivated by the special case where $P(X) = X^2 + 1$ that appeared in a math olympiad.

I was wondering if anyone can point me to references of this question.

Comment: Are you asking whether this holds for *every* single-variable polynomial with integer coefficients?

Comment: Yes I believe it might be. But could be gravely mistaken by missing the obvious.

Comment: There are conjectures, e.g., by G. Martin, about the density of $N$ such that $P(N)$ is $N^{1/d}$-smooth.  That might be enough to conclude that $P(N)$ divides $N!$.

Comment: I fixed the formatting and changed the wording a little. In the future, it would be better if you format your question using LaTeX. Two other comments. First, you said that "P(N) is a polynomial of finite degree". A polynomial, by definition, has finite degree. Second, it's best to distinguish the polynomial from its value.

Comment: @JoeSilverman, there is a weird colloquial useage where sometimes 'finite' is used in place of 'positive' (non-mathematicians will often try to emphasise that an unlikely event is not impossible by saying it has a 'finite probability'), and that might be what was meant here.  (Of course the conjecture is true by luck for constant polynomials, except $P = 0$.)

Comment: @LSpice I think in that usage "finite" means $0<x<+\infty$; it makes at least some sense in the context of infinite products $\prod_ia_i=\exp\left(\sum_i\log a_i\right)$ where a factor of 0 corresponds to a summand of $-\infty$.

Comment: @LSpice Since the statement is clearly true for non-zero constant polynomials, I guess the OP was using "of finite degree" to mean "degree not equal to $-\infty$", where by convention the zero polynomial is assigned degree $-\infty$. (This is the right value if you want to define the $x$-adic absolute value to be $|f(x)|=e^{-\deg(f)}$.) But none-the-less,   I think it's confusing to say "finite degree" instead of just saying that the polynomial is not the zero polynomial.

Comment: See also [Joni Teräväinen's answer at Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1370243/11619).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general this is an open problem.  A closely related problem (essentially equivalent) is to ask for the values $P(n)$ for $n$ of size $X$ to be $X$ smooth (i.e. composed only of primes below $X$).  This is known for quadratic polynomials, but already open for general cubic irreducible polynomials.  For some special polynomials (e.g. those of the form $ax^d+b$) such results are known, thanks to Schinzel, Balog and Wooley etc. For a description of related results, and more references, see this paper of [Dartyge, Martin and Tenenbaum](http://www.akademiai.com/doi/pdf/10.1023/A%3A1015237700066).

Comment: I agree. To elaborate briefly on "essentially equivalent": once $P(n)$ is $x$-friable, the only other test to pass is that the power of $p$ dividing $P(n)$ is at most the power of $p$ dividing $n!$, for all primes $p$. It's easy to show that most numbers are almost squareefree—say, only $O(x/\log x)$ numbers up to $x$ have a square factor larger than $\log x$—and that only $O(x/\log x)$ numbers up to $x$ are divisible by $p^r$ where $p<\log x$ and $p^r > \log^2x$. One has to adapt this to the set of values of a fixed polynomial, which requires some bookkeeping, but the principles are the same.

Answer (score 10):

Wow! I have been thinking about this problem, too. I can prove that for every **odd** natural number $d$ there exists infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n^{d}+1 \mid n!$. Here you have my gorgeous proof of the case $d=3$ of the result (cf. https://oeis.org/A270441):

For every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that

\begin{eqnarray*}(k^{6}+2k^{4}+k^{2}+1)^{3}+1 &=& (k^{2}-k+1)(k^{2}+2)(k^{2}+k+1) &\cdot& (k^{4}-k^{3}+2k^{2}-2k+1)(k^{4}+1)(k^{4}+k^{3}+2k^{2}+2k+1);\end{eqnarray*}

therefore, it follows that, for every $k \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$, the natural number $N_{k}:=k^{6}+2k^{4}+k^{2}+1$ is such that $N_{k}^{3}+1$ divides $N_{k}!$. QED.

I have to finish something else now, but if you are interested in what I have mentioned, I may add more details about the result that I obtained later on.

Comment: Do you have an algorithm to produce Q(k) such that P(Q(k)) is Q(k) smooth?  Gerhard "Belt Sander Is Not Working" Paseman, 2016.11.11.

Comment: Not that I know of...

Comment: @PietroMajer: You are absolutely right!

Comment: $N^3+1\mid N!$ is easy. See this question at [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1365712/11619). If you can give an elementary answer to $N^5+1\mid N!$, my bounty offer there can be renewed :-)