# Is Квант the actual source of this problem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

If I recall correctly, Andreescu & Andrica attributed the olympiad problem which prompted [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254440/integral-polynomial-divide-n/254459#254459) question by S. Pek to the Russian magazine Kvant. Does anybody here know if the problem actually appeared in the pages of Kvant once?

Hope this question of mine doesn't get closed... I dared to ask it here because I believe that several MO users were avid readers of Kvant back in the day.

Thanks in advance for your attention!

Comment: Looks like a perfectly legitimate question to me, fitting perfectly the reference request tag. Cannot see why it should be closed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is problem M618a), published in No. 4, 1980. Part b) claimed that for every $\alpha>0$ there exist infinitely many $n$ with $n^2+1\mid [\alpha n]!$. The problem is attributed to A. Sivatsky (who was a 10th grade student at that time).

The solution is in No. 2, 1981. Also, this problem is discussed in an article by V. Senderov and A. Spivak in No. 4, 2002. If you need, I may find a cite to the electronic versions of all these.

Comment: Links to the problem (http://kvant.mccme.ru/1980/04/zadachnik_kvanta_matematika.htm) and the solution (http://kvant.mccme.ru/1981/02/resheniya_zadachnika_kvanta_ma.htm).

Comment: @KConrad: Can you add a link to the article by V. Senderov and A. Spivak, too?

Comment: Here are the links to two first parts of this article: http://kvant.mccme.ru/pdf/2002/03/kv0302senderov.pdf  http://kvant.mccme.ru/pdf/2002/04/kv0402spivak.pdf     This problem appears as Exercise 30 on page 2 of the second part. (There second part is not the last one...)